# How to fold/unfold a DIV like on this website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really like the way the DIVs fold/unfold from the top to the bottom then left to right when users click on the menu items (about, services, my tools, etc) on this website. Seems that it has been developed by a very talented person.

Any idea how to achieve something like that? I was expecting this to be done via complex CSS animation, but looking at the CSS sheet that doesn't seem to be the case.

Many thank

Comment: You can view the CSS and HTML and JS on the site... why not just view it there?

Comment: It looks like they have the div positioned with a border and are simply changing the width/height over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that site it is achieved with the use of `jQuery UI` - more specifically with the [Fold Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/fold-effect/).

Answer (score 3):

I think using jQuery UI for this task alone would be an overkill, in fact you don't even need jQuery here, but I think you want to stick to it, since it's relatively easy both to read and to write code:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("#fold")
    .animate({ width: "500px" }, 1000 )
    .animate({ height: "500px" }, 1000 )
});
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/bartkarp/u3qtt6fo/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks for this example! If its not too much to ask could you just add one or two links to your example (like if it was a navigation menu) and the unfold functionality when clicking a second time on the link or on another link? So basically something closer to the website I took as example. I will then try to understand how it works line by line, many thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Greg, I've updated the fiddle :) Added a few extra comments as well, they should make it easier to grasp what's happening. I strongly recommend checking out jQuery documentation though.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `jQuery UI`, I guess you could do it by animating the css...:-??
First state is `height: 0;`  and `width :30px;` ...then using the animate on click event you could give the height a value and animation time, the width a delay equal o bigger than the height animation time and then it's value...that should do the trick but it's more stiff than actually using the `UI`